# ReactNative / Switch Component: onValueChange

Tags: react-native

I've trying to set up a change event if someone modifies a switch component. The approach is to design a view that contains multiple switches and allows the user to set the state per each notification that will end up in a POST api-call. Futher, I'd like to load the initial values from a api-call.

How can I access the state (weather it's checked / unchecked) in my onChangeFunction? And how can I get an element using their ID or name? (same as in HTML/CSS with #mySwitch.setValue(true)?

Given code:

```
class Settings extends Component {    
    onChangeFunction(type, props) {
        Alert.alert("changed", "==> " + props.state)
    }    

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Switch onValueChange={this.onChangeFunction.bind(this, "TASK_CREATED", this.props)} value={this.state} />
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have a mess there between the `props`and the `state` concept. You can do:

```
class Settings extends Component {

  state = {
      taskCreated: false,
  };

  onChangeFunction(newState) {
      this.setState(newState, () => Alert.alert("Changed", "==> " + this.state));
  }

  render() {
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Switch onValueChange={(value) => this.onChangeFunction({taskCreated: value})}
                    value={this.state.taskCreated}
            />
        </View>
      );
  }
}
```

Notice that `this.setState` is asynchronous so you can safely read its value using the callback that the method provides.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. How can I access the name of the Switch and it's new value in the onChangeFunction? I want to build this method generically, so I can do a rest call like this: /api/updatePush?type=taskCreated&value=ON|OFF?

Comment: `<Switch ref={(s) => this.switch = s} ... />` and then `this.switch`

Comment: Well as you can see, when we call `this.onChangeFunction` we pass `{taskCreated: value}` so... that variable I called ```newState``` would be an object which key `taskCreated` and its `value` which is what you want for your api call. If it gets easier for you, you can also do: ```onValueChange={(value) => this.onChangeFunction('taskCreated', value)}```.

Comment: I've tried both but none of these do work with multiple boxes. I'd imagine something like this, but the state of the Switch always turns back after change:

`<Switch onValueChange={(value) => this.onChangeFunction({value: value, name: "taskCreated"})} value={this.state.taskCreated} />`

with the method:

`onChangeFunction(newState) {
        this.setState({checkedValue: newState.checkedValue}, () => Alert.alert("-> " + newState.name, "==> " + newState.value));
    }`

Comment: From this last code, the value of that Switch is `value={this.state.taskCreated}` right? So you need to do `this.setState({taskCreated: newState.value}`. Or... `const tmp = {}; tmp[newState.name] = newState.value; this.setState(tmp)`.

Comment: great, this works and I understood the concept of state.